Need Help Implementing Real-Time Progress Output in Translation Loop Using JConsole
I'm struggling to print 'translating text x / y' one at a time. Currently, all the translation progress is outputted at once once the loop completes. JConsole, which I'm using, is a basic JFrame-based console with a TextArea added to it.
My code
System.out.println("Translating " + scrapedTextCollection.size() + " results...");
// Perform translation...

int count = 0;
for (Map<String, String> mappedText : scrapedTextCollection) {
    count++;
    MainClient
        .getClientExtension()
        .getJConsole()
        .writeInformation("Translating text" + count + " /  " + scrapedTextCollection.size());
    String translatedResult = Translator
        .translate(Language.valueOf("ENGLISH"), Language.valueOf("SPANISH"), mappedText.get("Title") + " - " + mappedText.get("Chunk Text"));
    mappedText.put("Translated Text", translatedResult);
}

I have tried all sorts of things but its not working. Any help would be great. After some time using the swing worker solution down below it only iterates the Collection once and it just suddenly stops after the first iteration. The collection during debug could have a size of like 8, 10, whatever but it only loops once and it breaks. If I call .get() it works but it doesn't write information in real time. I am still having issues with this regarding this post, any additional help would be great I've circling around this for days. Honestly this just makes no sense

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TranslationTask extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
    private List<Map<String, String>> scrapedTextCollection;
    private JConsole console;

    public TranslationTask(List<Map<String, String>> scrapedTextCollection, JConsole console) {
        this.scrapedTextCollection = scrapedTextCollection;
        this.console = console;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Map<String, String> mappedText : scrapedTextCollection) {
            count++;
            publish("Translating text " + count + " / " + scrapedTextCollection.size());
            String translatedResult = Translator.translate(Language.valueOf("ENGLISH"), Language.valueOf("SPANISH"), mappedText.get("Title") + " - " + mappedText.get("Chunk Text"));
            mappedText.put("Translated Text", translatedResult);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String message : chunks) {
            console.writeInformation(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        console.writeInformation("Translation complete.");
    }
}

// Usage
TranslationTask task = new TranslationTask(scrapedTextCollection, MainClient.getClientExtension().getJConsole());
task.execute();

doInBackground(): Runs on a separate thread. The translation process happens here.
publish(): Sends intermediate results (the progress messages) to the
process() method.
process(): Runs on the EDT and updates the GUI with the messages.
done(): Runs on the EDT after
doInBackground() completes. It can be used to indicate the completion of the task.
In doInBackground(), each text is translated, and a progress message is published.
process() updates the TextArea in the GUI with the current progress message.
This approach ensures that your GUI remains responsive and updates the progress in real-time.

(1+) Read the section from the Swing tutorial on Concurrency for more information about the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and SwingWorker.

@Tijil Saka After some time it seems to only iterate once and it just suddenly stops after the first iteration. The collection has a size of like 8, 10, whatever but it only loops once and it breaks. If I call .get() it works but it doesn't write information in real time
